# Inherit wrapper from abstract method

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, wrapper, abc

I would like to systematically wrap some overriden method of a base class.

I am using `ABC` for the base class. I tried to wrap the `@abstractmethod`, putting the annotation before or after, but it doesn’t work. As I understand it, the the whole wrapped method is overriden.

```py
from functools import wraps
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

def print_before(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def out(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Hello')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return out

class Base(ABC):
    @print_before
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        pass

class Extend(Base):
    def test(self):
        print('World')
```

Here is what happens when we test:

```py
Extend().test()
```

Result:

```
World
```

Desired:

```
Hello
World
```

I guess I’m not using the right method to get such behavior. What would be a nice pythonic way to run some code before and after an overriden method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed, the decorator does not change overridden methods. You could decorate the method every time you create a subclass. You can even do it automatically with the magic method `__init_subclass__`.

```
class Base(ABC):
    ...

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.test = print_before(cls.test)
```

But i would not recommend this approach. It will probably destroy the `ABC` mechanisms and classes that inherit from `Extend` are decorated twice if they don't override the method.

Here is a much easier approach. We define a concrete "public" method on `Base` that calls an abstract "private" method. In the child classes we then have to implement the "private" method.

```
class Base(ABC):
    def test(self):
        # do something before
        result = self._do_work()
        # do something after
        return result

    @abstractmethod
    def _do_work(self):
        pass


class Extend(Base):
    def _do_work(self):
        # your implementation here

# use it like this:
e = Extend()
e.test()
```

Another advantage is that you can change the behaviour of the "wrapper" in a child class which would be difficult with the decorator.

Comment: Thanks, your second solution is quite clever!